# Can i skip davening to help out at home?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, minyan, shalom-bayit

Is it OK to skip davening in order to help out my wife at home with the kids?

Comment: Are you asking based in the principle of osek b'mitsvah pattur min hamitsvah? If so, consider noting that.

Comment: Is this in addition to or instead of her skipping Minyan?

Comment: @DoubleAA Only the 1st question is a duplicate.

Comment: @Loewian Well then either it's too broad or a dupe. Either way no reason for a reopen vote.

Comment: @DoubleAA How is it too broad?

Comment: @Loewian Multiple questions in one post. However you figure, it makes no sense to open a whole nother thread because it adds one additional subquestion. That's totally inefficient and misses the whole point of the duplicate system.

Comment: @DoubleAA More so than e.g. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16144/matza-on-14-iyar ?

Comment: @Loewian Probably not. But that doesn't make opening this a good idea at all. There's a reason I went for dupe over too broad. Most of the post is a dupe. We don't need to rehash it all.

Comment: Plus the answer to both is the same: he's Tarud and Oseik BeMitzva (not to mention a Meshmesh to an effective Choleh in many cases); of course he's exempt if he needs to be (in most cases a parent could just wake up 7 minutes earlier; we're talking about where he's stuck and needs to deal with the kids).

Comment: The point is does this mean that he wants to skip davening all together or just skip minyon and daven at home (either before or after helping with the children)>

Comment: @sabba the answer is the same